# Why is my Rails erb page not showing changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

My rails erb view page is not updating with my changes.

I have made changes to my index.html.erb file directly. I restarted the WEBrick. killed -9 all running ruby processes. Clear browser cache, opened page in a different browser. No dice.

Rails 2.3.8
Ruby 1.9.2
gem 1.3.7

I search stackoverflow, found some matches nothing

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about some code? What environment are you running webrick?

Answer (score 3):

Had exactly the same issue. I found a solution to complement the webserver virthost conf with "RackEnv development":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName someserver
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/rails/public/"
    RackEnv development

    <Directory "/path/to/rails/">
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The post is corrpupted for some reason. Just add "RakeEnv development" to the VirtualHost section.

Comment: you didn't mark your code as code. As the code contains tags and SO interprets tags they were missing.

Answer (score 2):

by any chance did you cache enabled. If so in your /public folder you can find  static index.html file if so remove it

another symptom would be you have another file with the extension of .erb or .rhtml with the same name. (index.erb or index.rhtml). If so remove it

cheers

sameera

Comment: All good thoughts, but cache is disabled. I have already deleted the index.html. I do not have any conflicing files in my public dir.

Comment: Hi, Wht i mean by index.erb or index.rhtml files in your app/views directory. coz i have experience that if you have a test.rhtml and test.erb file it first take the test.rhtml file

Comment: try config.cache_classes = false and config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true in your env file - sameera

Answer (score 0):

Then your RAILS_ENV environment variable must be set to 'production'. Change it to 'development', that will cause your code to be "re-compiled" on each request. **Except** if you create a new locale file (like fr.yml), you have to restart your server.

Comment: To clarify the index.html.erb is not the root index file, sorry this was probably misleading. This is the index file in view directory for custom view/controller.

Comment: I am working off a custom environment for our QA/stage mode. It is based on development env. Here it is:

Comment: I can't seem to format code here, so here's a link to my enviroment: https://gist.github.com/670624